# Convert plain text to PDF in Python

Tags: python, text, reportlab

For my project, I get a plain text file (report.txt) from another program.  It is all formatted in plain text. If you open it in Notepad, it looks nice (as much as a plain text file can). When I open the file in Word and show the paragraphs, I see the ... for spaces and the backwards P for pararaph.

I need to convert this file to PDF and add some other PDF pages to make one final PDF. All this happens in Python.

I am having trouble converting the report.txt to pdf.  I have ReportLab, and am able to read the file and make a few changes (like change the text to Courier), but the spacing gets lost. When the file gets read, it appears to strip any extra spaces.

Questions:
a) is there an easier way to convert the report.txt to pdf?
b) If not, is there a way to keep my spaces when I read the file?
c) Or is there a parameter I'm missing from my paragraph style that will keep the original look?

Here's my code:

```
# ------------------------------------
# Styles
# ------------------------------------

styleSheet = getSampleStyleSheet()
mystyle = ParagraphStyle(name='normal',fontName='Courier',
                         fontSize=10, 
                         alignment=TA_JUSTIFY, 
                         leading=1.2*12,
                         parent=styleSheet['Normal'])       

#=====================================================================================       
model_report = 'report.txt'

# Create document for writing to pdf  
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(str(pdfPath),  \
                        rightMargin=40, leftMargin=40, \
                        topMargin=40, bottomMargin=25, \
                        pageSize=A4)
doc.pagesize = portrait(A4)

# Container for 'Flowable' objects
elements = []    

# Open the model report
infile   = file(model_report).read()
report_paragraphs = infile.split("\n")

for para in report_paragraphs:  
    para1 = '<font face="Courier" >%s</font>' % para 
    elements.append(Paragraph(para1, style=mystyle))
doc.build(elements)
```

Answer (score 10):

I've created a small helper function to convert a multi-line text to a PDF file in a "report look" by using a monospaced font. Too long lines are wrapped at spaces so that it will fit the page width:

```
import textwrap
from fpdf import FPDF

def text_to_pdf(text, filename):
    a4_width_mm = 210
    pt_to_mm = 0.35
    fontsize_pt = 10
    fontsize_mm = fontsize_pt * pt_to_mm
    margin_bottom_mm = 10
    character_width_mm = 7 * pt_to_mm
    width_text = a4_width_mm / character_width_mm

    pdf = FPDF(orientation='P', unit='mm', format='A4')
    pdf.set_auto_page_break(True, margin=margin_bottom_mm)
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font(family='Courier', size=fontsize_pt)
    splitted = text.split('\n')

    for line in splitted:
        lines = textwrap.wrap(line, width_text)

        if len(lines) == 0:
            pdf.ln()

        for wrap in lines:
            pdf.cell(0, fontsize_mm, wrap, ln=1)

    pdf.output(filename, 'F')
```

This is how you would use this function to convert a text file to a PDF file:

```
input_filename = 'test.txt'
output_filename = 'output.pdf'
file = open(input_filename)
text = file.read()
file.close()
text_to_pdf(text, output_filename)
```

Comment: brilliant! would you mind posting a version to convert a txt file to pdf too?

Comment: thanks again, @m13r! that benefits lots of people!

Comment: Would you mind giving some advises in the line spacing in text paragraphs?  I've tried to adjusted the "pdf.ln()" and "ln=1" but they only change the line breaks between paragraphs, not the line spacing amongst lines in the same paragraph. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

ReportLab is the usual recommendation-- as you can see from the "Related" questions on the right side of this page.

Have you tried creating text with just `StyleSheet['Normal']`? I.e., if you get proper-looking output with the following, the problem is somehow with your style.

```
Paragraph(para1, style=StyleSheet['Normal'])
```

Comment: Normal doesn't work, hence why I was trying to create my own.

Comment: Since Normal *should* work, I'd suggest you figure out why it doesn't. Copy-paste an example from the documentation, and if it still doesn't work, there's something wrong with your installation of ReportLab. Then add `report.txt` to the mix and if that breaks it, check your file encoding-- might you have UTF16 instead of ascii? Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

For converting text or text file into pdf, module fpdf shall be installed using **pip install fpdf** in *command-line Interface*.
run the below code and you will find the pdf file in folder-

```
from fpdf import FPDF 
pdf = FPDF()      
# Add a page 
pdf.add_page()  
# set style and size of font  
# that you want in the pdf 
pdf.set_font("Arial", size = 15)
# open the text file in read mode 
f = open("path where text file is stored\\File_name.txt", "r") 
# insert the texts in pdf 
for x in f: 
    pdf.cell(50,5, txt = x, ln = 1, align = 'C') 
# save the pdf with name .pdf 
pdf.output("path where you want to store pdf file\\File_name.pdf")
```

reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-text-and-text-file-to-pdf-using-python/

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I solved with this code:

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
from PIL import Image

# .....
# ..... some exta code unimportant for this issue....
# ....


# here it is
ptr = open("tafAlternos.txt", "r")  # text file I need to convert
lineas = ptr.readlines()
ptr.close()
i = 750
numeroLinea = 0

while numeroLinea < len(lineas):
    if numeroLinea - len(lineas) < 60: # I'm gonna write every 60 lines because I need it like that
        i=750
        for linea in lineas[numeroLinea:numeroLinea+60]:      
            canvas.drawString(15, i, linea.strip())
            numeroLinea += 1
            i -= 12
        canvas.showPage()
    else:
        i = 750
        for linea in lineas[numeroLinea:]:
           canvas.drawString(15, i, linea.strip())
           numeroLinea += 1
           i -= 12
        canvas.showPage()
```

Pdf looks exactly same as original text file

Comment: Could you edit to show how you created the canvas and the pdf file?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a canvas with `pdf_canvas = canvas.Canvas('output_file.pdf')` and generate the PDF with `pdf_canvas.save()`.